# check if parentNode is undefined

Tags: jquery

I'm getting a TypeError where the parentNode is undefined. How can I check if the parentNode is undefined?

Here is my method:

```
    function updateImages(myRow) { 
        var rowInputs =  j$(myRow).find('input[type="text"]');
        var contact = (j$(rowInputs[0]).val()); 
        var user = (j$(rowInputs[1]).val());
        var account = (j$(rowInputs[2]).val());

        if (contact !== '') {
            j$(rowInputs[0].parentNode).find('img').show();
            j$(rowInputs[1].parentNode).find('img').hide();
            j$(rowInputs[2].parentNode).find('img').hide();
        }    
        else if (user !== '') {
            console.log('user is not blank');
            console.log(j$(rowInputs[1]));
            console.log(j$(rowInputs[1].parentNode));
            j$(rowInputs[0].parentNode).find('img').hide();
            j$(rowInputs[1].parentNode).find('img').show();
            j$(rowInputs[2].parentNode).find('img').hide();
        }
        else if (account !== '') {
            j$(rowInputs[0].parentNode).find('img').hide();
            j$(rowInputs[1].parentNode).find('img').hide();
            j$(rowInputs[2].parentNode).find('img').show();
        }
        if (account !== '' && contact !== '') {
            j$(rowInputs[0].parentNode).find('img').show();
            j$(rowInputs[1].parentNode).find('img').hide();
            j$(rowInputs[2].parentNode).find('img').hide();
        }
    }
</script>
```

I need to check if the parentNode for rowInputs[1].parentNode is undefined and if the parentNode for rowInputs[2].parentNode is undefined.

Thanks for any help.
Regards.

Comment: Is there always 3 inputs in each `myRow`?

Comment: if (typeof rowInputs[1].parentNode == 'undefined')

Comment: Just as an aside, you should really DRY that code up.

Comment: Is it possible for an element in the DOM to not have a `parentNode`? Or is `rowInputs.length != 3`?

Comment: Good point, there is not always 3 inputs in each `myRow`.  I'm new to jquery, so my apologies for any novice questions here.  What do you mean by DRY up the code?

Comment: DRY means "Don't repeat yourself." It's programming concept, not a jQuery one.

Comment: When you access an element of a jQuery collection by index, you get back a DOM element, and are no longer using jQuery. I would recommend `rowInputs.eq(0)` instead to return a jQuery object. You should probably also check `rowInputs.length` to make sure elements exist before trying to reference them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a suggestion:

```
function updateImages(myRow) { 
    var rowInputs =  j$(myRow).find('input[type="text"]');
    var contact = rowInputs.eq(0); 
    var user = rowInputs.eq(1);
    var account = rowInputs.eq(2);

    var cont = contact.parent().find('img');
    var usr = user.parent().find('img');
    var aco = account.parent().find('img');

    if (contact.val() !== '') {
        cont.show();
        usr.hide();
        aco.hide();
    }    
    else if (user.val() !== '') {
        console.log('user is not blank');
        console.log(user);
        console.log(user.parent());
        cont.hide();
        usr.show();
        aco.hide();
    }
    else if (acontount.val() !== '') {
        cont.hide();
        usr.hide();
        aco.show();
    }
    /* This is redundant same as first if
    if (acontount.val() !== '' && contact.val() !== '') {
        j$(rowInputs[0]).parent().find('img').show();
        j$(rowInputs[1]).parent().find('img').hide();
        j$(rowInputs[2]).parent().find('img').hide();
    }
    */
}
```

You code assumes there are always 3 elements per row and probably throw error because of that. If you use [**.eq()**](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) instead you always get a jQuery object and no `undefined` error. If you post your html maybe we can find a better way to optimize the code.